# distplay:table tag export links appear on top in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am using `<display:table>` in my JSP to display a list of data.

**Here is my JSP code:**

```jsp
<display:table name="Clients" class="table table-condensed table-hover" requestURI="" id="ClientList" export="true" pagesize="5">
        <display:column property="clientKey" sortable="true" href="editMClient" media="html"
            paramId="clientKey" paramProperty="clientKey" titleKey="mClient.clientKey"/>
        <display:column property="clientKey" media="csv excel xml pdf" titleKey="mClient.clientKey"/>
        <display:column property="MClientcol" sortable="true" titleKey="mClient.MClientcol"/>
        <display:column property="clientName" sortable="true" titleKey="mClient.clientName"/>

    <%--Many columns --%>

 </display:table>
```

I want to display the export options to be set on top of table, not in the bottom.

I checked in [Display Tag Library - Configurations](http://www.displaytag.org/10/configuration.html), but it has option for paging banner to set on top, bottom or both. I don't find the same for export.

Is there any option for setting it, so that I can specify in `displaytag.properties` file.

And also, rows to be displayed on each page, I am setting to `5`. Like jqGrid, is there any way to change that dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

The `div` has the class `exportlinks` that you should override via CSS technique. In this case you could customize the appearance of the bar.

To change `pagesize` dynamically you need to customize the banner and place `select` there, then `onchange` event should handle the change `pagesize="<s:property value="pagesize"/>"` by submitting the value from the select or sending it in GET request. After the value is changed by the action just keep return or refresh the page to take changes effect.